# Stanford coreNLP sentiment analysis debug takes too much time

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

CoreNLP model load during debugging to much time.

```
String line="surat is good city";
```

CoreNlp Demo

> [main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator tokenize
>
> [main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.TokenizerAnnotator - No tokenizer type provided. Defaulting to PTBTokenizer.
>
> [main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ssplit
>
> [main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator pos
>
> [main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger - Loading POS tagger from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger... done [566.7 sec].
>
> [main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator parse
>
> [main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.parser.common.ParserGrammar - Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz ... done  [390.8 sec].
>
> [main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator sentiment

Comment: You should ask a specific question.

Comment: during the debugging CoreNLP for sentiment analysis my POS tagger and parse tagger takes too much time.... see the times.

Comment: That is a statement. What is it that you want help with, and how far have you gotten trying to do it on your own?

Comment: try to solve for days. First, I think its because I gave it a long sentence but after tried on this small sentence. it took the same time ...

Comment: The problem appears to not be the length of the sentences, but the fact that it takes 566 seconds to load the POS tagger and 390 seconds to load the grammar parser. How are these files stored?